# OR Matching a vector across a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given an arbitrary vector,

```
vec = [1 5 2 3]
```

and an arbitrary matrix with the same number of columns,

```
M = [ 2  1  3  5 
      1  5  3  1
      8  9  4  0
      1  0  5  6 
      1  5  2  3 ]
```

Is there any elegant way of matching vec across the rows of M so that we get an output which is 1, if vec shares at least one *corresponding* component with the row, and 0 otherwise.

```
out = [ 0
        1
        0
        1 
        1 ]
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
out  = any(bsxfun(@eq,M,vec),2)
```